Logging with Rust WebAssembly Modules
I get the following error when executing:
"wasmer foo_bar.wasm"
error: Instantiation failed
1: Error while importing "wasi:logging/logging"."log": unknown import. Expected Function(FunctionType { params: [I32, I32, I32, I32, I32], results: [] }
My build command is " cargo build --target=wasm32-wasi"
I first attempted to use the crate log4rs but apparently that does not work with the wasm32-wasi target.  The wasi-logger was my second attempt and it showed promise, however I believe my Cargo.toml file is missing critical definitions which resulted in the above error. Somehow I need to trigger the wasm module output to include the dependencies.
Here is my Cargo.toml:

[package]
name = "foo_bar"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
[dependencies]
log = "0.4.6"
wasi-logger = "0.1.1"


Here is the code:
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
extern crate wasi_logger;

fn main() {
    wasi_logger::Logger::install().expect("failed to install wasi_logger::Logger");
    //log::set_max_level(log::LevelFilter::Info);

    info!("Hello world");
}

`
